# How can I simplify after applying both the product rule and power chain rule?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The book says that this:
$$
(x^2 + 4)^2 (3)(2x^3-1)^2(6x^2) + (2x^3-1)^3(2)(x^2+4)(2x)
$$
simplifies to this:
$$
2x(x^2 + 4)(2x^3-1)^2(13x^3+36x-2)
$$

I don't understand how that worked. Should I use FOIL on the terms, then add? How can I use FOIL if there are four elements that are multiplied together?

Comment: You should first take the common terms out and then simplify the rest.

Comment: FOIL would technically work, but it would at the same time hide what is going on here behind half a page of boring and uninstructive calculations.

Comment: How would I take out the common terms?

Comment: $18 x^2 (x^2 + 4) + (2 x^3 - 1) 4 x=2x(13x^3+36x-2)$

Comment: @user6050977 $(x^2+4)$ and $(2x^3-1)^2$ can be taken common from both terms

Comment: So it's (3)(6x^2) = 18x^2, multiplied by just one of (x^2+4)? What happens to the ^2 portion of (x^2+4) - does it just disappear? How?

Comment: @user6050977 Please see my answer for an explanation of how to remove like terms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x^2 + 4)^2 (3)(2x^3-1)^2(6x^2) + (2x^3-1)^3(2)(x^2+4)(2x)$

We start by multiplying together the constants in the equation. I added color to show the like terms. Please tell me if those detract from the answer.

$18 \color{blue}{x^2}\color{red}{(x^2 + 4)^2} \color{green}{(2x^3-1)^2} + 4\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{(2x^3-1)^3}\color{red}{(x^2+4)}=$

Now we combine like terms

$2x(x^2+4)(2x^3-1)^2(9x(x^2+4)+2(2x^3-1))$

Finally, we multiply out the inside and add like terms.

$2x(x^2+4)(2x^3-1)^2(9x^3+36x+4x^3-2)$

$2x(x^2+4)(2x^3-1)^2(13x^3+36x-2)$

Comment: "2x(x^2+4)" - Where does this come from? Did the 2x come from 18x^2? How?

Comment: @user6050977 $18x^2=2x\cdot 9x$

Comment: So 18x^2 gets split apart? Why is this necessary? How will I know which elements I need to split apart?

Comment: How does "+4x (2x^3-1)^3(x^2+4)" become "(9x(x^2+4)+2(2^x-3))"? How does the plus become a multiply? Why do the red and green elements switch places? Where does the 2 come from? Why is there an addition between the red and green elements, when it was a multiplication before?

Comment: Try to read something about the Greatest Common Factor, for numbers and polynomials.

Comment: I've never been able to understand technical explanations for math. I can only solve problems if I see how they are done, and memorize the patterns involved for other problems.